# Python: Relative imports

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a package that has the following structure:
[image]

The file prova.py contains only the following line:

```
import bipartite_class
```

while bipartite_class.py has the following initial lines:

```
from .nes import *
from .mod import *
from .graphs import *
from .contrib import *
from .null import *
from .tests import *

from getref import *

import pickle
import tempfile
import os
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

import os.path
```

When I try to compile prova.py I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bipartite_class
  File "/Desktop/CD_BEST/Bipartito/bipy-master/bipy/bipartite_class.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .nes import *
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

If I try to remove the dots in bipartite_class.py I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prova.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bipartite_class
  File "/Desktop/CD_BEST/Bipartito/bipy-master/bipy/bipartite_class.py", line 1, in <module>
    from nes import *
  File "/Desktop/CD_BEST/Bipartito/bipy-master/bipy/nes/_init_.py", line 5, in <module>
    from nodf import *
  File "/Desktop/CD_BEST/Bipartito/bipy-master/bipy/nes/nodf.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..mainfuncs import *
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with \_\_init\_\_.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

Comment: Remove the dots!

Comment: I think my case is different, since I try to compile a file that is not inside a folder. Added the error I get when I remove the dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using this: https://github.com/tpoisot/bipy and that `prova.py` is your addition (it would be nice if you include this kind of information in your question in future questions!)

The problem is that `bipartite_class` is not a free-standing module, but is a part of the package `bipy`. That means you need to import it from outside the package. You need to move `prova.py` one directory up, to `bipy-master`, and change its contents to:

```
from bipy import bipartite_class
```

and then you should be able to run `prova.py`.

---

Even better would be to actually *install* bipy. Because the project includes a `setup.py`, you can run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Then you can import `bipy` from anywhere, so you can put your programs that use it in their own directory.